# Run an atmega328 using an 16Mhz crystal with 22nF caps

Tags: arduino, capacitor, atmega, crystal

Can you run an ATmega328 using an 16Mhz crystal with 22nF capacitors instead 22pF?

Comment: You can use 0.022 nF caps if you want.

Comment: If it runs at all, it will ignore the crystal and run at a frequency determined by the capacitors - probably several kHz rather than 16 MHz.

Comment: You may be able to improvise approximations to 22pF caps sufficient to get it running at least while waiting for some to arrive.  (You can actually use an Arduino to measure capacitances in this range!)  Also consider scrounging old electronics.  The oscillator will probably run over a range of values, though for ultimate accuracy you need to look at your crystal specs and take you pcb or breadboard into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use 22nF instead of 22pF, it just wont work. Here you can read more about it.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00826a.pdf